# Help Me Understand This Binary File Format

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, file-format

I am attempting to write a small utility to produce a binary file that will mimic the one produced by another closed application.  I've used hex editors to decrypt the format by I'm stuck trying to understand what the format/encoding is so that I can produce it using C++ or C#.

The file starts with the first four bytes: 01 00 followed by FF FE.  My understanding is that the file begins with SOH followed by the byte order mark for little endian.  After these four bytes, the program appears to write BSTR's for each of the string fields from the app's GUI.

Using C#, I have produced a unicode file that starts with FF FE, but I'm not sure how to insert the SOH character first.

I would be forever grateful if someone could offer insight to the file format or encoding and why the file starts with the SOH character.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give us a hint about what this closed software does? Can you at least say which industry or area of endeavor it is associated with?

Comment: The file is produced by a GUI that automates the backup of an object oriented and a SQL database while creating a file that is used to restore the backup.  I want to create an executable that can produce the same file using arguments so that I can automate the backup and produce a file that could be used by the GUI to restore my scripted backup.  I'm not attempting to bypass any licensing or produce something to sell.  It's just for an app that will saving me from running the backups manually.  The file is only 1k in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just having trouble writing out the first four bytes this will do it for you.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("myfile.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
     using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream))
     {
         binaryWriter.Write((byte)1);
         binaryWriter.Write((byte)0);
         binaryWriter.Write((byte)0xFF);
         binaryWriter.Write((byte)0xFE);
         binaryWriter.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("string"));
     }
}
```

This will output the following file

```
01 00 FF FE 73 00 74 00 72 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00  ....s.t.r.i.n.g.
```

Edit: Added Mark H's suggestion for writing out a string.

Answer (score 4):

**Reverse engineering a binary file format can be a challenging task.** On the surface, I don't recognize this as an obvious, well-known file format ... but there are thousands out there, so who knows.

[Legal issues](http://www.chillingeffects.org/reverse/faq.cgi) aside, I would suggest you look at some of the following resources that talk about approaches to such an endeavor:

- [How To Crack a Binary File Format](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_HTCABFF.html)
- [Tools to Reverse Engineer Binary Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492751/tools-to-help-reverse-engineer-binary-file-formats)
- [Basics of Reverse Engineering File Formats](http://upe.acm.jhu.edu/websites/John_Rittenhouse/reverse.html)
- [File Format Reverse Engineering](http://nada-labs.net/2010/file-format-reverse-engineering-an-introduction/)