# What algorithms/techniques can be used to detect code within a memory dump?

Tags: algorithm, reverse-engineering

i'm looking for an algorithm/technique that would enable me to detect code from a given memory dump.

For instance I can make the program learn a new language. A new language would be a set of instructions that respects a given grammar.

By giving to the program a set of hex values (random data + code) I would like to determine the probability that a code that respects the language's grammar is present.

Comment: well.. the probability is 1 or 0 - you can determine it by checking if any substring of your input is valid in respect to your language...

Comment: Seriously though, this is a bold endeavor, but far too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. Also, you seem to be completely ignoring the "compilation" stage.

Comment: may be it is possible to get a kind of "score" by using the "index of coincidence" technique in order to determine if a given random input (bytecodes) looks like more to a given language or not (?) ...

what do you think?

Comment: You can build a language model by dumps of program code, using bytes (and maybe 2, 4 and 8 bytes sequences - you need some knowledge of instructions' format) as the language's words. Then you can detect code of the same instruction set in an arbitrary dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492751/tools-to-help-reverse-engineer-binary-file-formats) [tools](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/what-tools-exist-for-excavating-data-structures-from-flat-binary-files) like this out there already, so you might want to look at existing implementations to see how they do it.

That said, if I was writing this from scratch, my first idea would be to build an [*n*-gram model](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) model of the data, and compare it with a similar model of the type of code we're looking for.  The Wikipedia article seems a bit heavy on theory and low on practical implementation details, but basically, here's how you could do this:

1. Collect a large "reference corpus" of the kind of code you're looking for.
2. Break the code in the reference corpus into (overlapping) pieces of, say, three bytes, and count how many times each piece ("tri-gram") occurs in the corpus.  This is your basic raw *n*-gram model, for *n* = 3 and bytes as the basic data units.
3. Increment all the *n*-gram counts by one; this is called [additive smoothing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing), and makes the matching process more robust.
4. Precalculate the (*n*−1)-gram (i.e. 2-gram) counts by summing up the (smoothed) 3-gram counts that begin with each two-byte prefix.  Also precalculate the total sum of *all* the smoothed 3-gram counts.  (This is just the total byte length of the reference corpus, minus *n*−1 = 2 times the number of separate files in it, plus 256<sup>3</sup> for the smoothing.)
5. For better matching speed and numerical stability, take the logarithm of all the (smoothed) 3-gram and 2-gram counts (and the total count).  Store these as your actual (smoothed, logarithmic) *n*-gram model.  (Conveniently, log(1) = 0, so by adding 1 and taking the logarithm, any 3-gram counts that were originally zero before smoothing become zero again; if you have a lot of these, consider only storing the non-zero counts.)
6. Using this preprocessed *n*-gram model, you can loop over the input file and calculate the approximate log-likelihood that it matches the reference corpus as the sum of the log-counts of every 3-gram found in the input file, minus the log-counts of every 2-gram found in the input file (except the first and the last), minus the logarithm of the total sum of the smoothed 3-gram counts.  I'll skip the detail of the math here, since this is SO, not [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but trust me, it works.

The resulting raw number is of little use by itself (although you can get something a bit more meaningful by dividing it by the length of the input), but can be usefully compared with the corresponding log-likelihood value for *other* *n*-gram models.  The one with the largest result is the most likely match.

In particular, as a baseline "null model", you may wish to compute the log-likelihood of the input being purely random bytes.  You don't have to actually build an *n*-gram model of random data to do that; the log-likelihood of the input being purely random bytes is just −log(256) times the length of the input in bytes (which is why dividing the log-likelihoods by the input length before comparing them can be useful).

(As a consistency check of your implementation, you may wish to check that this is also the log-likelihood you'll get if you build a smoothed *n*-gram model from an empty corpus.)

Finally, if you suspect that your input may contain a mix of different types of data, you could simply break it up into chunks before analyzing it. Alternatively, you can compute a [running average](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of the log-likelihood over a moving window of some suitable size (say, a couple of kilobytes) by subtracting the log-counts of each 3-gram (and adding those of each 2-gram) that falls out of the window from the log-likelihood, as you move along the input file.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for this you gave me a lot of clues to explore.
I was actually reading these slides https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-08/Conti_Dean/BH_US_08_Conti_Dean_Visual_Forensic_Analysis.pdf regarding "Visual Forensics". The approach I was trying a couple of days was to determine an average bytes distribution over a set of code. Then by computing a running average while parsing the binary file, I might use the Pearson Correlation to determine if two bytes distribution look the same or not.

What do you think?